# How does a conductor in electrostatic equilibrium have no interior electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, conductors

Can't you construct a Gaussian surface small enough to surround only one of the interior protons, thus the surface has a charge enclosed and a electric field by Gauss's law.

Comment: Do note that in using Maxwell's equations in materials, the Maxwellian fields are spatially averaged fields inside the materials, specifically chosen so that the atomic nature of the charges inside would not give the behaviour that you are correctly asserting must happen. This process is extremely difficult and nobody has yet given a completely satisfactory averaging scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a conductor in equilibrium the electric field vanishes only at scales much larger than that of atoms. At shorter scales it is zero on average.

Answer (score 0):

As @naturallyInconsistent points out in the comment, Maxwell's equations in matter are spatially averaged and *smoothed out* over a chosen region. In the case of the general dielectric (where the case of a perfect conductor is accounted for by letting $\epsilon$ tend to infinity), the correctness of the averaged fields derives from the fact that the average field inside a sphere due to all the charges inside is the same as the field at the center of a uniformly polarized sphere with the same total dipole moment:
$$ \boldsymbol{\mathrm{E}}_\text{ave} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}}}{R^3} $$
for a sphere of radius $R$ and total inside dipole moment $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}}$. For an in-depth calculation, you could refer to Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics* section 4.2.3.

Another point I would like to add is that "something which in electrostatic equilibrium has no interior electric field" is just the *definition* of a perfect conductor. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_conductor) states:

> A perfect conductor ... is an idealized material exhibiting infinite electrical conductivity or, equivalently, zero resistivity.

According to Ohm's law
$$ \boldsymbol{\mathrm{E}} = \rho\boldsymbol{\mathrm{j}}, $$
this *asserts* that $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{E}}=0$.

Comment: In a general dielectric the electrical field is not zero.
Why do you bring it up?

Comment: As far as I know, the averaged fields (macroscopic fields) concept normally comes up with the introduction of *Maxwell's equations in matter*, which is closely related to dielectrics.